# AFNETWORK singleton class,Swift

Tags: swift, afnetworking-2

I am trying to write a singleton class in Swift to handle all my http requests using AFNetworking's AFHTTPRequestOperationManager class and came across the issue where my delegates for multiple requests using this class where firing off in the wrong order. So I thought a solution would be to add the operations to a queue but can't seem to get it working, getting an error saying "operation is already enqueued on a queue"

import UIKit

```
var apiURL:NSString = "http://www.api.com"

protocol NetWorkManagerDelegate {
    func requestSuccess(didSucceed response:NSArray)
    func requestFailure(didFail response:NSError)
}

class NetworkManager: AFHTTPRequestOperationManager {

    struct Singleton {
        static let sharedInstance = NetworkManager(url: NSURL(string: apiURL))
    }

    class var sharedInstance: NetworkManager {
        return Singleton.sharedInstance
    }

    var delegate:NetWorkManagerDelegate?

    init(url:NSURL)
    {
        super.init(baseURL: url)
        self.responseSerializer = AFJSONResponseSerializer()
        self.requestSerializer = AFJSONRequestSerializer()
    }

    func requestData(urlString:NSString)
    {
        var operation = self.GET(urlString,
            parameters: nil,
            success: { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!, responseObject: AnyObject!) in
                self.delegate?.requestSuccess(didSucceed: responseObject as NSArray)
                println(responseObject)
            },
            failure: { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!, error: NSError!) in
                self.delegate?.requestFailure(didFail: error)
                println(error)
            }
        )

        self.operationQueue.addOperation(operation)
    }


}
```

Here's how I use the class in my view controller

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool)
{
    var networkManager:NetworkManager = NetworkManager.sharedInstance
    networkManager.delegate = self
    networkManager.requestData("categories")
}

func requestSuccess(didSucceed response: NSArray)
{
    self.menuItems = response as NSArray
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}

func requestFailure(didFail response: NSError)
{
    println("Error!")
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I was able to find a solutions by abandoning the delegate pattern and opting for using a closure as a callback. Here my new singleton class

```
import UIKit

var apiURL:NSString = "http://www.api.com"

class NetworkManager: AFHTTPRequestOperationManager {

    struct Singleton {
        static let sharedInstance = NetworkManager(url: NSURL(string: apiURL))
    }

    class var sharedInstance: NetworkManager {
        return Singleton.sharedInstance
    }

    init(url:NSURL)
    {
        super.init(baseURL: url)

        if (self != nil) {
            self.responseSerializer = AFJSONResponseSerializer()
            self.requestSerializer = AFJSONRequestSerializer()
        }

    }

    func requestData(urlString:String, completion:(data:NSArray?, error:NSError?) -> ())
    {
        var operation = self.GET(urlString,
            parameters: nil,
            success: { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!, responseObject: AnyObject!) in
                completion(data: (responseObject as NSArray), error: nil)
            },
            failure: { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!, error: NSError!) in
                completion(data: nil, error: error)
            }
        )
    }


}
```

And here is my view controller, note the requestData method now implements a closure as a callback

```
    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool)
    {
        var networkManager:NetworkManager = NetworkManager.sharedInstance
        networkManager.requestData("categories") {
            (data:NSArray?, error:NSError?) -> () in
            if (data != nil) {
                self.requestSuccess(didSucceed: data!)
            } else if (error != nil) {
                self.requestFailure(didFail: error!)
            }
        }
    }

    func requestSuccess(didSucceed response: NSArray)
    {
        self.menuItems = response as NSArray
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }

    func requestFailure(didFail response: NSError)
    {
        println("Error!")
    }
```

If anyone know a better way let me know, just learning Swift here.